# Is it possible to sell membership plans on a website using shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I have a client who wants to sell memberships on a website that is not a shopify store. They insist on using Shopify to handle the paid membership because they have separate shopify store. I am struggling to determine if this is feasible.

The plan is to create a product named "membership" and utilize Appstle to manage the subscriptions. On the website, we would utilize the Shopify/Appstle API and webhooks to synchronize the user's membership status. I have searched for examples of a similar approach but haven't found any.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at it this way. Shopify has structured itself for many years to try and get away from the "You must use a Shopify store" to sell things. Hence you can now sell on eBay, Amazon, and almost any other sales channel you want. You have the buy button. Basically as Tobi once said, if it runs code, you can sell your Shopify item on it.

So you have to embrace that by doing your homework. If your client insists on selling something of theirs on a website that is NOT Shopify, this fits what Shopify pushes. That website is just a sales channel.

So at a minimum, you can whip up a Sales Channel App, and use that pattern. And of course, if you understand Shopify well enough, you could probably also try some other patterns. It is on you.

I caution you against thinking you'll just find an App to do it all for you though. You might! It might even be 99% perfect! But I sense you're unique needed here will be serviced best by something you craft specifically for this store. Especially in light of wanting to sell subscriptions.

Comment: thanks. I was looking for examples or recommended patterns. a quickstart guid like stripes offers. https://docs.stripe.com/billing/quickstart

Comment: You mean copy and paste glory? Nah.. you gotta do some work yourself.

Comment: I mean like stripe - which took me a few hours to implement and thankfully we might just use it 
But if you have resources/links or a pattern in mind, it would be great to explain it.  I am not seeing any value in your answer to be honest. Perhaps my question is too broad.

Comment: My advice to you was clear. Make yourself a sales channel App, to sell subscriptions on a foreign non-shopify website. Sorry that was not clear.

Comment: So a sales channel app allows api access, one need the api to create and manage checkout. At minimum one can use the JS shopify buy sdk or something similar to sell the product on an external website. This is how far I got.  then one need to worry about user and webhook, webhook need to infrom downstream systems that a user purchased a subscription/memebrship ..etc and the downstream app/website can act on it. Anyway, thank you. If I get around a working POC I will detail the steps and answer my own question. Shopify docs are so confusing